# Returning multiple xml Children with same name on single node using linq c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following XML and want to return all "schools" children but I only get the first one.  (jeffersion/08.36)  I looked high and low and banged my head.  What am I missing?

```
<users>
  <user>
    <role>janitor</role>
    <schools>
      <school_name>jefferson</school_name>
      <keycode>80.36</keycode>
      <school_name>mainline</school_name>
      <keycode>64.36</keycode>
      <school_name>south side</school_name>
      <keycode>31</keycode>
    </schools>
  </user>
</users>
```

This is only returning the first record.

```
var results= from schools in myXmlDoc.Descendants("schools")
                   select new 
                   {
                       SchoolName = schools.Element("school_name").Value,
                       KeyCode = schools.Element("keycode").Value
                   };
```

I've also tried:

```
var results= (from schools in myXmlDoc.Descendants("schools")
                   select new 
                   {
                       SchoolName = schools.Element("school_name").Value,
                       KeyCode = schools.Element("keycode").Value
                   }.ToList();
```

This gets the values BUT only for the first school:

```
var schools = (from c in xml.Descendants("user")
                      select new
                      {
                          Name = c.Element("role").Value,
                          Fields = c.Elements("schools")
                              .Select(f => new
                              {
                                  SchoolName = f.Element("school_name").Value,
                                  Keycode = f.Element("keycode").Value
                              }).ToArray()
                      }).ToList();
```

Comment: You are aware of the missing `>` in your xml file? <school_name>mainline</school_name>
      <keycode>64.36</keycode`>` I can imagine why you won't get more results from a xml file that isn't wellformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one `<schools>` element in your source, which is why only one entry is being returned. The XML isn't particularly nicely structured - it would be good to have a `<school>` element containing each school_name/keycode pair. But assuming you have to live with it, the following should work:

```
var results= from school in myXmlDoc.Descendants("school_name")
               select new 
               {
                   SchoolName = school.Value,
                   KeyCode = school.ElementsAfterSelf("keycode").First().Value
               };
```

Comment: THANK YOU NICK!  You hit the nail on the head too.  I have to live with the XML because I'm getting it from an API.

Answer (score 1):

This may be helpful:

var result = from c in XElement.Load("Student.xml").Elements("schools") 
          select c ;

// Execute the query 
foreach (var students in result ) 
{ 
     //do something
}

Comment: my friend also recommended me to add this statement, it helps at end and i did not understood why.AddRange(results);